# UIWebView does load URLs different that mobile Safari?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiwebview, mobile-safari

I use a `UIWebView` and want to load the following urls:

```
http://feratel.lueneburger-heide.de/lhg/de/accommodation/detail/LUH/8634e147-e13d-40f5-8954-2ac40cfea2a7/romantik_hotel_bergström?customHeader=true

http://feratel.lueneburger-heide.de/lhg/de/accommodation/detail/LUH/8af6d1fd-af6d-4765-8025-9eb8fa05ea42/hotel%20undeloher%20hof?customHeader=true
```

When you load the above urls in mobile Safari and in a UIWebView you get different results. Not in terms of rendering the page, but the final page which is shown to the user is a different one.

Here is the code I use with iOS7:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate {
  @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
  var request: NSURLRequest!
  var urlString: String!
  private var isDone: Bool = false
  private var failedRequest: NSURLRequest!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var userAgent = ["UserAgent": "mozilla/5.0 (iphone; cpu iphone os 7_0_2 like mac os x) applewebkit/537.51.1 (khtml, like gecko) version/7.0 mobile/11a501 safari/9537.53"]
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(userAgent as [NSObject : AnyObject])


    urlString = "https://buchung.salonmeister.de/ort/301655/menue/#offerId=907601&venueId=301655"
    request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
    webView.delegate = self
  }

  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    self.webView.loadRequest(self.request)
  }

  // MARK: UIWebViewDelegate

  func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    println("shouldStartLoadWithRequest()")

    if !isDone {
      isDone = false

      println("shouldStartLoadWithRequest() 111")
      failedRequest = request
      webView.stopLoading()
      var connection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)
      connection!.start()
      //      NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self)
      return false
    }
    println("shouldStartLoadWithRequest() -----------------------")
    return true
  }

  func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: UIWebView) {
    println("webViewDidStartLoad()")
  }

  func webViewDidFinishLoad(aWebView: UIWebView) {
    println("webViewDidFinishLoad()")
  }

  func webView(webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: NSError) {
    println("webView(): didFailLoadWithError(): \(error)")
  }

  // MARK: NSURLConnectionDataDelegate

  func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge) {
    println("connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge")

    if challenge.previousFailureCount == 0 {
      self.isDone = true
      println("x1")
      let credential: NSURLCredential = NSURLCredential(forTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!)
      challenge.sender.useCredential(credential, forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge)

    }
    else {
      println("x2")
      challenge.sender.cancelAuthenticationChallenge(challenge)
    }
  }

  func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse) {
    println("connection didReceiveResponse")
    self.isDone = true

    connection.cancel()
    self.webView.loadRequest(self.failedRequest)
  }

  func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace protectionSpace: NSURLProtectionSpace) -> Bool {
    println("connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace")
    return protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust
  }
}
```

**How can I force a UIWebView to load URLs like mobile Safari does?**

Edit: Here is how it looks when I use the following url:

```
http://feratel.lueneburger-heide.de/lhg/de/accommodation/detail/LUH/8af6d1fd-af6d-4765-8025-9eb8fa05ea42/hotel%20undeloher%20hof?customHeader=true
```

in UIWebView:

[image]

and here is how it looks in mobile Safari:

[image]

Comment: i tried loading the url but nothing was shown to me, after i escaped some of the string in the url, it loads as same as the mobile safari

Comment: @T_77 Could you please post an answer if it works for you.

Comment: it would be great if you post the screenshot of how it behaved at your side.

Comment: can you try this url and see if both are the same http://feratel.lueneburger-heide.de? on safari and on webview?

Comment: @T_77 I checked your url. I get different results in Safari I get the mobile site and in my WebView I do not get the mobile version.

Comment: can you remove the customHeader=true part and try the URL ?

Comment: try this in webview http://feratel.lueneburger-heide.de/lhg/de/accommodation/detail/LUH/8af6d1fd-af6d-4765-8025-9eb8fa05ea42/hotel%20undeloher%20hof?

Comment: @T_77 I tried this: http://feratel.lueneburger-heide.de/lhg/de/accommodation/detail/LUH/8af6d1fd-af6d-4765-8025-9eb8fa05ea42/hotel%20undeloher%20hof but it gives the same result. Could you please post your useer agent string then I can try if it works with yours.

Comment: sorry, wht is user agent string? and how do i get it?

Comment: Okay l used your user agent but still don't get the mobile page.

Comment: I have no idea then sorry.

Comment: @T_77 Could you please post the code you use in your answer?

Comment: I already posted it, It is just a one line of code that load s the webview with the URL

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[image]This worked for me :

```
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://feratel.lueneburger-heide.de/lhg/de/accommodation/detail/LUH/8634e147-e13d-40f5-8954-2ac40cfea2a7/romantik_hotel_bergstrom?customHeader=true"]]];
```

I need to replace the  'ö' with 'o' character in the URL

Comment: i didnt take care of the constraints, but they both are showing the same content

Comment: and also you need to escape some part of the string

Comment: the first one is the safari and the second image is the webview

Comment: Does I work with both urls for you? Replacing ö with o will give a different url?

Comment: What did you do? What did you change?

Comment: i didnt do anything, as I mentioned in the code, I used the same URL as you do, but I changed the o character in the first URL and I didnt change anything in the second URL. If you could post a screenshot, how it differs at your side, I can get a better understanding.